# How to avoid Flutter widgets and blocs from rebuilding when keyboard is popped open

Tags: flutter, widget, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a chat widget screen wrapped within a Bloc builder checking state of the bloc [HydratedBloc] handling the socket connection. Whenever I try to open the keyboard from the textfield each and every bloc registered on the bloc provider refreshes at once and the keyboard is immediately dismissed (at times it actually sort of crashes/freezes), but no error is logged.

Chat screen (left screenshot) and the frozen chat screen (right screenshot):

[image]

[Screen Recording](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7830d2d8ecbf0aa5febe29aae59a6abd20230222121745/66087a)

```dart
class HekimaSupportPage extends StatelessWidget {
  HekimaSupportPage({super.key});

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RelativeBuilder(
      builder: (context, height, width, sy, sx) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: context.height,
          width: context.width,
          child: BlocBuilder<SupportChatBloc, SupportChatState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              late Widget chatWidget;
              if (state is SupportChatConnecting) {
                chatWidget = const Center(
                  child: LoaderWidget(
                    color: AppColors.background,
                  ),
                );
              } else if (state is SupportChatNotConnected) {
                chatWidget = ExceptionWidget(
                  exception: AppException(
                    'Sorry, failed to connect properly with chat service.',
                    title: 'Chat not connected',
                  ),
                  titleColor: Colors.black,
                  buttonColor: AppColors.background,
                  buttonTextColor: Colors.white,
                  onRetry: () =>
                      context.read<SupportChatBloc>().add(ConnectSupportChat()),
                );
              } else if (state is SupportChatException) {
                chatWidget = Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: sx(20),
                  ),
                  child: ExceptionWidget(
                    exception: state.exception,
                    titleColor: Colors.black,
                    buttonColor: AppColors.background,
                    buttonTextColor: Colors.white,
                    onRetry: () => context
                        .read<SupportChatBloc>()
                        .add(ConnectSupportChat()),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                chatWidget = SupportChatWidget(
                  messages: state.messages,
                  formKey: formKey,
                  messageController: messageController,
                );
              }

              return AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                child: chatWidget,
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class SupportChatWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SupportChatWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.messages,
    required this.formKey,
    required this.messageController,
  });

  final List<models.Message> messages;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;
  final TextEditingController messageController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RelativeBuilder(
      builder: (context, height, width, sy, sx) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: context.height,
          width: context.width,
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: sy(35),
                  width: context.width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: sx(20),
                  ),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColors.background,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Hekima Support',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: sy(9),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        CupertinoIcons.info,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: sy(16),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: context.width,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: sx(20),
                      vertical: sy(10),
                    ),
                    child: ListView(
                      reverse: true,
                      children: messages
                          .map((Message message) =>
                              MessageBubble(message: message))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                MessageSenderWidget(
                  controller: messageController,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class MessageSenderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageSenderWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RelativeBuilder(
      builder: (context, height, width, sy, sx) {
        return Container(
          width: context.width,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: sy(32),
            maxHeight: sy(50),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: sx(20),
          ),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColors.background,
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: sy(8),
                  ),
                  controller: controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Text Message',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: sy(8),
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 3,
                  minLines: 1,
                ),
              ),
              const Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.photo_on_rectangle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: sx(15),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (controller.text.isEmpty) {
                    return;
                  } else {
                    final Message message = Message(
                      type: MessageType.chatMessage,
                      message: controller.text.trim(),
                      messageFrom: '',
                      messageTo: '',
                    );
                    context.read<SupportChatBloc>().add(SendMessage(message));
                    controller.clear();
                  }
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  CupertinoIcons.arrow_up_circle_fill,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to define the messgecontroller inside the [MessageSenderWidget] and make the widget const, also inside blocBuilder there's method called (buildWhen), use it

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the messgecontroller inside the [MessageSenderWidget] and make the widget const, also inside blocBuilder there's method called (buildWhen), use it

Comment: Okay, this worked by adding the buildWhen method